# DOM event delegation or not, which is best resourcewise?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events

**Context:**

- HTML with a long table with many rows and many columns.
- Each cell contains additional elements and sub-elements.
- In the last cell on every row, different buttons but same for each row

**Question:**

In this setup, resourcewise for the browser (fluidity, loading time, responsiveness,...) it it best to :

1. Use a single delegate click handler on the `<table>` element ? This would be triggered by any click on any other cell or sub-element and basically triggered many more times for just nothing.
2. Use an event handler on every `<button>` on every row ? This would add many handlers but each would run only once when needed.
3. An alternative ?

Is there a real difference for the browser itself ? (*lets not consider coding practices*)

In the (1) delegate case, doesn't the browser have to somewhat add listeners to every child element to know it has been clicked ?

Comment: The answer it it depends. Attaching an event listener to every button on every row, is of course gong to cost you more in terms of memory, but it may be faster. I usually don't bother and instead just attach a single listener for an ancestor element, like an entire table, checking `target` property against a list of interest or I `switch` on the target or the name of the target. Event dispatching was an order of magnitude slower than equivalent number of function calls when I profiled it last time in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principal *performance* advantages of event delegation in the case you describe are

1. You only have to hook up a handler once, rather than looping through all the rows to do it. But if you have a table so big that hooking up the handlers to the buttons is a slow operation, you're likely to have other performance issues with that table.
2. A **minor** memory savings (the event registrations).

There isn't a performance disadvantage to worry about if it's a `click` handler. (That might not be true of, say, a `mousemove` handler.)

There are code complication and maintenance issues to consider (delegated handler is *slightly* more complicated to write; hooking up the handler to each button is easier to get wrong if buttons are added dynamically at some point), but you've said you're principally concerned about performance.

> In the (1) delegate case, doesn't the browser have to somewhat add listeners to every child element to know it has been clicked ?

No, just the one event listener. What happens is that clicks *bubble*. Here's a diagram from the old [DOM3 events spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) (I can't find this diagram or an equivalent in the now-canonical [WHAT-WG DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/), which is unfortunate):

[image]

The handler is only attached to the one element. It's found when the click bubbles (propagates) to that element.

> 1. Use a single delegate click handler on the `<table>` element ? This would be triggered by any click on any other cell or sub-element and basically triggered many more times for just nothing.

That's true, but it's harmless. The amount of work required is virtually nil.

> 2. Use an event handler on every `<button>` on every row ? This would add many handlers but each would run only once when needed.

You don't need many *handlers*, you can reuse the same function for multiple buttons. It's just multiple *registrations* of handlers:

```
function buttonHandler(event) {
    // ...
}
// ...
for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll(".selector-for-button")) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler); // Adds a registration, not
                                                  // an additional function
}
```

That doesn't create a new function for each button, it reuses the same function for all of the buttons. During the call, `event.currentTarget` will refer to the specific button that was clicked (the one we hooked up the handler to). (If the button has child elements, `event.target` may refer to one of those children, but `event.currentTarget` will refer to the button.)

So in any given situation, you have to weigh those various considerations to decide what you want to do.

Comment: Your last point to reuse the same function [and not use an anonymous one in a loop] is good ;)